# Famo.us - this.add and this_add

Tags: this, addition, famo.us

What is difference betwen using this.add and this._add in Famo.us framework. I am little confused with that _add part (naimin conventions that underscore in front of variable or method name 'mimics' private variable or method), but in code ther is no _add method.

Example:

```
 function _createStripViews(){

    this.stripViews = [];
    this.stripModifiers = [];

    var stripData = [
        {title: 'APPAREL', iconUrl: './img/apparel_icon.png', stripColor: '#00aaac', textTitle: './img/apparel_text.png'},
        {title: 'FOOTWEAR', iconUrl: './img/footwear_icon.png', stripColor: '#006a6d', textTitle: './img/footwear_text.png'},
        {title: 'ALL MATERIALS', iconUrl: './img/allMaterials_icon.png', stripColor: '#be326a', textTitle: './img/allMaterials_text.png'},
        {title: 'CHEMISTRY', iconUrl: './img/chemistry_icon.png', stripColor: '#32900e', textTitle: './img/chemistry_text.png'},
        {title: 'ENERGY/GREENHOUSE GAS', iconUrl: './img/energyGreenhouse_icon.png', stripColor: '#cc4300', textTitle: './img/energyGreenhouse_text.png'},
        {title: 'WATER/LAND', iconUrl: './img/waterLand_icon.png', stripColor: '#1a81b6', textTitle: './img/waterLand_text.png'},
        {title: 'PHYSICAL WASTE', iconUrl: './img/physicalWaste_icon.png', stripColor: '#ccb200', textTitle: './img/physicalWaste_text.png'},
        {title: 'RECYCLED', iconUrl: './img/recycled_icon.png', stripColor: '#7d0ea2', textTitle: './img/recycled_text.png'},
        {title: 'ORGANIC', iconUrl: './img/organic_icon.png', stripColor: '#6c00c7', textTitle: './img/organic_text.png'}
    ];

    for(var i = 0; i < stripData.length; i++){

        var stripView = new StripView({
            width: this.options.stripWidth,
            height: this.options.stripHeight,
            title: stripData[i].title,
            color: stripData[i].stripColor,
            iconUrl: stripData[i].iconUrl,
            textTitle: stripData[i].textTitle,
            index: i
        });

        this.stripViews.push(stripView);

        var yOffset = this.options.topOffset + this.options.stripOffset * i;

        var stripModifier = new Modifier({
            transform: Transform.translate(0, yOffset, 0)
        });

        this.stripModifiers.push(stripModifier);
        this._add(stripModifier).add(stripView);

        stripView.pipe(this);
        stripView.on('tap', this.animateStrips.bind(this));

    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no difference. If you look at the file View.js in the Famo.us framework you will see the following..

```
/**
 * Alias for add
 * @method _add
 */
View.prototype._add = View.prototype.add;
```

They are the exact same thing. My guess is that if you want to add an 'add' function to a custom view, you may still reference Views 'add' function using _add.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are famous in famo.us (and JavaScript :P ) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `_`-prefix  is a common pattern in JavaScript when programming in an object oriented manner. It usually means that a instance method/variable is intended as private or protected as JavaScript doesn't really let you do that in a nice way.

Hence, even if you can use both and they currently do exactly the same, I'd advice to use the `.add` as it's probably the one that is supposed to be publicly exposed.